# Does having a master's equal being a Master?

Tags: meaning

If an English major graduates from college, must one say,

*She has a Bachelor of Arts*?

May one instead say,

*She is a Bachelor of Arts*?

*He has a master's*

is certainly correct, but might one say,

*He is a Master of Science*?

Comment: I am a native AmE speaker, and we do not use the degree in that manner. I do refer to *Master Carpenters* and some other skilled craftsman (guilded, usually). But for degrees, I hear, he has a bachelor's/master's. For the highest degree, though, it's not incommon to see someone described as a Doctor of Philosophy (e.g. at Yale, etc.)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I can't quite work out what you meant to say, but _superlative_ doesn't mean anything to me that is relevant to the question.

Comment: @medica - What if you go to school for Bating?

Answer (score 1):

It's not common to say *She's a Bachelor of Arts*, but I think it would be understood.

It would not be understood if you left out the *of Arts*.

Note that *They're all PhDs* is at least as common as *They all have PhDs*. But I don't think many people would say *He's a Doctor of Philosophy*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a citation, but in the American graduate school where I studied, we were taught (informally) that academic ranks were historically related to old medieval guild structure.

Although today we wouldn't refer to someone as a "Master" because of their M.S., scholars of the past would have recognized someone with an M.A. as a Master in their trade.

It is common to refer to people with a Ph.D as "Doctor", which is an exception to this rule.